# How to set up Visual Studio to refresh tray icons after debug session ends?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, system-tray, notifyicon, trayicon

I'm working on a c# app which has a tray icon, and every time I stop the debug session from visual studio the icon doesn't disappear by itself. I have to hover the cursor over it for it to go away. Is there a way I could make VS refresh the whole icon tray so that the icon doesn't stay there?